# How to plot a MultiIndex Xarray?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science, python-xarray

I am trying to plot my MultiIndex Xarray in jupyter using Matplotlib and Holoviews. I can plot a very basic plot using matplotlib but I get errors otherwise.

My xarray is this -

[image]

I am using this code to plot my spectrogram with matpllotlib and some in-house function of xarray to find the max value in the matrix that I want to plot.

```
# Plotting in some other way 
plt.figure(figsize=(3,5))
data_slice = temp1
max_value = np.log(temp1.max(xr.ALL_DIMS)['__xarray_dataarray_variable__'].values)
xr.ufuncs.log(data_slice).plot(cmap='magma', vmin=0, vmax = max_value*.7)
```

In this code I get the error  - KeyError: '**xarray_dataarray_variable**'

When I am plotting the spectrogram using holoviews I use this code -

```
# plotting the new xarray that we got - 2 dimenntional
# making an array that represents the freq bins
final_freqs = np.linspace(0, 125000, 257)

time_to_see = 10
time_stamps_to_be_displayed = [[] for _ in range(165)]
for x in range(0, 55):
    # multiplying it by 0.01 to get it to seconds as each window is for 10 miliseconds. 
    time_stamps_to_be_displayed[x].append(time_to_see + x * 0.005)

time_displayed = np.array(time_stamps_to_be_displayed).flatten()

xr_spec = xr.DataArray(temp1, dims = ('freq','time') ,coords = {'freq':final_freqs,'time':time_displayed})

xr_spec.name = 'Spectrogram'

# plotting the graph 
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')

import os
os.environ['HV_DOC_HTML'] = 'true'
#%env HV_DOC_HTML=true

import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
hv.extension('bokeh')
output_notebook()
import imp
imp.reload(hv)

hv_spec = hv.Dataset(xr_spec)
hv.extension('bokeh')
hv_spec.to(hv.Image, ['time', 'freq'])
```

In this, I get the error - unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list' for the very last line.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

StackTrace is here - 
[image]

Comment: Can you please post the full [stacktrace](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/)? It's helpful for us to understand what's going on. Generally, plotting with a multiindex dimension is difficult and frequently breaks. If you don't care about the categories, you could just call `da.assign_coords(dim_new=np.arange(len(da.dim_new)))` as you pass it into your plotting function to relabel the multiindex dim to a positional index.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I added the stacktrace. I hope this helps you a little more to understand my problem. Basically it cannot understand the variable 'xarray_dataarray_variable'.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado `da.assign_coords(dim_new=np.arange(len(da.dim_new)))` what does da stand for in this expression?

Comment: Oh sorry - that's shorthand for whatever `xarray.DataArray` you are working with. It's used pretty frequently in xarray docs and examples, along with `ds` for `xarray.Dataset` objects, sort of like `df` for `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and the dataset representation as a code block? [Posting code and data as images is strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3888719) on stack overflow for a variety of reasons. Here's a set of general [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking questions. Thanks! :)

Comment: Also - the error indicated in your stacktrace "KeyError" is not the error you mention in your question "Unsupported operatnd". Can you make sure that your code and stacktrace reflect the issue you're asking about? Otherwise we might be debugging different things :)

Comment: Ok so basically, I talk about the two codes that I use to plot the xarray, both of them give different errors. One gives the key error and the other(were i am using holoviews) gives me unsupported operand. I provided you with the stacktrace for the first problem. And sure I will post these things as a code block. Sorry for that.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I am sorry I forgot to tag you in the previous comment.